# Form submission returns 'array'

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to send through POST the name of some hotels, the code, and the e-mail address to a new page that will send an email to the checked hotels. So far, though, what I'm really trying to do it send the data to a new php which only `echo`s them. What I've worked on so far is:

```
<form action='chior.php' method='post'>
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($counter as $obj => $nr_rez) {
    $nume_hotel = $hoteluri[$obj];
    $localitate = $localitati[$obj];       //all this arranges the data from a sql query
    $email       = $emailuri[$obj];
    $total_rez += $nr_rez;
    $cprest     = substr($cprest, 3, 10);
    $parametri  = "cp=$cprest&dstart=$data_start_af&dstop=$data_stop_af";
    $email      = str_replace(";", ";\n", $email);

    echo "<tr class='mainRow'> <td> $i </td> 
               <td><input type='text' name='hotelul[$i][]' value='".$cprest."' readonly/> </td> 
               <td><a href='link.php?$parametri' target='_blank'>$nume_hotel</a></td> 
               <td> $localitate </td> 
               <td> $nr_rez </td> 
               <td><input type='text' name='hotelul[$i][]' value='". $email ."'/></td>
               <td><input type='checkbox' id='$i' name='hotelul[$i][]'/></td>
          </tr>";
$i++;
}
?>
<input type='submit'/> </form>
```

There's a bit of the page I haven't posted, for brevity's sake (various tags and css elements to make the page look nicely), but it works on my end. The only problem is that the page I'm sent to after clicking submit - chior.php, which looks like this `<?php  echo $_POST['hotelul'];?>`, returns 'Array'. I've also tried `<?php  echo implode('/', $_POST['hotelul']);?>` , `<?php  echo implode('-', implode('/', $_POST['hotelul']));?>` , `<?php  echo $_POST['hotelul[][]']` , which was pretty much all I could think of and it still did not work. Does anyone have any ideea why that is and how I could fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `echo` use `print_r()`

Comment: <?php  echo $_POST['hotelul'];?> returns an array because you are using hotelul[$i][] as the input name. Make it hotelul and you will not receive an array. In your case, it makes sense to use the input name like hotelul[]. On the server side, you will receive an array of all the hotel names entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes**

**1)** Change `name='hotelul[$i][]'` to `name='hotelul[]'`

**2)** All `input` names are `hotelul`. Change to some other name to avoid ambiguity.

**Updated Code:**

```
<form action='chior.php' method='POST'>
  <?php
  $i = 0;
  foreach($counter as $obj => $nr_rez) {
    $nume_hotel = $hoteluri[$obj];
    $localitate = $localitati[$obj];
    $total_rez += $nr_rez;
    $cprest     = substr($cprest, 3, 10);
    $parametri  = "cp=$cprest&dstart=$data_start_af&dstop=$data_stop_af";
    $email      = str_replace(";", ";\n", $emailuri[$obj]);

    echo "<tr class='mainRow'>
            <td> $i </td> 
            <td><input type='text' name='hotelul[]' value='".$cprest."' readonly/> </td> 
            <td><a href='link.php?$parametri' target='_blank'>$nume_hotel</a></td> 
            <td> $localitate </td> 
            <td> $nr_rez </td> 
            <td><input type='text' name='hotelul_email[]' value='". $email ."'/></td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' id='$i' name='hotelul_chkbox[]'/></td>
          </tr>";
    $i++;
  }
  ?>
  <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

**chior.php**

```
<?php
$checkedHotels = sizeof($_POST['hotelul_chkbox']);
for($i = 0 ; $i < $checkedHotels; $i++){
  $checked_hotel_email = $_POST['hotelul_email'][$i];

  //Write your mail function here to send mail to all checked hotels using `$checked_hotel_email`.

}?>
```

Comment: So, in the end, is there no way to make two-dimensional arrays in forms?

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

`<td><input type='checkbox' id='$i' name='hotelul[$i][]'/></td>`

which means that hotelul is containing a list (array). If you want to save a single value, remove `[]`;

The `name[]` sintaxis is used when you want to `$_POST['name']` to be a list. Like this:

```
<input type="text" name="email[]" />
<input type="text" name="email[]" />
<input type="text" name="email[]" />
```